# Finding the point where the two roots are equal from Finding Root

Tags: equation-solving

```
k[r_, a_, \[Alpha]_] = a^2 + r (r - 2) + r^2\[Alpha] Exp[-2r/\[Alpha]];
```

`FindRoot[ k[r, 0.9,0.4]==0,{r,2}];`
`FindRoot[ k[r, 0.9,0.4]==0,{r,0}]`
Suppose it has two roots. I want a short code for getting the `\[Alpha]` value for a constant value `a` where the two roots are equal. Kindly help me out.

Comment: `In[13]:= Solve[Discriminant[k[r, a, alpha], r] == 0, alpha]

Out[13]= {{alpha -> (1 - a^2)/a^2}}`

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to do analytically:

```
k[r_, a_, α_] = a^2 + r (r - 2) + r^2 α;

Solve[k[r, a, α] == 0, r]
(*    {{r -> (2 - Sqrt[4 - 4 a^2 (1 + α)])/(2 (1 + α))},
       {r -> (2 + Sqrt[4 - 4 a^2 (1 + α)])/(2 (1 + α))}}    *)

Solve[(2 - Sqrt[4 - 4 a^2 (1 + α)])/(2 (1 + α)) ==
      (2 + Sqrt[4 - 4 a^2 (1 + α)])/(2 (1 + α)), α]

(*    {{α -> (1 - a^2)/a^2}}    *)
```

So the roots are equal if $\alpha=a^{-2}-1$: in this case, there's a double root at $r=a^2$,

```
k[r, a, a^-2 - 1] // FullSimplify
(*    (a^2 - r)^2/a^2    *)
```

Comment: Okay, now it is easy, but suppose it is not solved using Solve like this kind of function. ```k[r_, a_, α_] = a^2 + r (r - 2) + r^2 α Exp[-r/α ]```

Answer (score 3):

For the more complicated example given in your comment to Roman's answer to your initial simpler problem:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

k[r_, a_, α_] = a^2 + r (r - 2) + r^2 α Exp[-r/α];
```

Use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) to look at the solutions

```
plt = With[{a = 9/10},
   ContourPlot[k[r, a, α] == 0,
    {α, 0, 2}, {r, 0, 2},
    PlotPoints -> 25,
    MaxRecursion -> 5,
    WorkingPrecision -> 15]];
```

[`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) the [`Gridlines`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gridlines.html) to estimate the values of `{α, r}` with a single solution

```
Manipulate[
 Show[plt,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {α, r}),
  GridLines -> {{α1}, {r1}},
  GridLinesStyle -> Red],
 {{α1, 0.75}, 0, 2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r1, 0.92}, 0, 2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

For a single root, maximize `α` starting from the estimates

```
{max, arg} = 
 With[{a = 9/10}, 
  FindMaximum[{α, 
    k[r, a, α] == 0}, {{r, 99/100}, {α, 77/100}},
   WorkingPrecision -> 20]]

(* {0.74537370559660576230, {r -> 0.92423817269034913569, α -> 
   0.74537370559660576230}} *)

k[r, 9/10, α] /. arg

(* 7.6524*10^-15 *)
```

Alternatively, also require `∂α/∂r == 0` to use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html), and again start from the estimates

```
arg2 = With[{a = 9/10}, 
  FindRoot[{k[r, a, α] == 0, 
    ImplicitD[k[r, a, α] == 0, α, r] == 0},
   {{r, 99/100}, {α, 77/100}},
   WorkingPrecision -> 20]]

(* {r -> 0.92423817269033426346, α -> 0.74537370559659194260} *)

k[r, 9/10, α] /. arg2

(* 0.*10^-20 *)
```

Comment: Thank you.  But I wish to get the exact point up to four precision. So how can I get the exact point from the plot?

Comment: No numerical technique (e.g., `FindRoot`, plotting) will provide an exact solution, only a numerical approximation. And exact numbers have infinite precision, not four. The results provided by either `FindMaximum` or `FindRoot` above are much better than four precision. You can `Round`, `Rationalize`, or `RootApproximant` them to a less precise result that is simpler looking.